# Why does string in UITextView determine keyboard case instead of capitalizationType on delete

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

If all of the characters of a UITextView is uppercase and the delete key is pressed it automatically assumes the character that should be inputted should be uppercase.  How can I disable this while keeping sentence case on the UITextView.  Whats even crazier is that new characters do not activate the capitalization key on the keyboard.  Here is a minimal example.  Press the delete key and look at the caps key which will then be active.  Type more text and it will not do this.  The goal would be for to honor the capitalizationType unless the user changes it to upper case. If there is a way to deselect the caps button programmatically that would be great as well. If you make capitalizationType equal to none then this behavior does not happen.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var textView : UITextView = {
        let tv = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 40, width: self.view.bounds.width - 40, height: 200))
        tv.autocapitalizationType = .sentences
        return tv
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(textView)
        textView.text = "THIS IS A TEST TO SEE WHAT THE KEYBOARD DOES"
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you delete an uppercase, so it returns an uppercase. If deletion of a lower case, it would not change the Cap key status.

Comment: I figured this but is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Also I forgot to mention but if you change the .none on the autoCapitalizationType deleting and uppercase letter does not do this.

Comment: You cannot change this system behavior. Its triggered by keyboard only and not other source.